# Определить, что больше всего места на диске занимает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

Я пользуюсь командами:

```
df -h
du -sh /your-folder
```

но это неудобно, так как приходится много каталогов руками перебирать...

Как определить, что больше всего занимает места на диске?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ncdu` запустить. Она построит дерево директорий с указанием размеров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую с ключем -x, чтобы она не выходила за границы ФС

Answer (score 5):

[Disk Usage Analyzer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DiskUsageAnalyzer) (также известен как baobab)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можно и не перебирать руками, а использовать `*`, чтобы на одном уровне размер всех каталогов посмотреть:

```
du -sh /*
```

Или даже на два уровня:

```
du -sh /*/*
```

Но визуальные тулзы, конечно, нагляднее.

Comment: `ncdu`, всё-таки, удобнее.